# How to navigate to a section of a page using animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in one page, if we have html like this

and we click on  tag it will navigate to particular section, that's fine

```
<a href="#shushi">Sushi</a>
<a href="#bbq">BBQ</a>

Sample Page:
<div id='sushi'></div>
<div id='bbq'></div>
```

but is it possible to add some animation effect when we click on it shushi and bbq and navigate to that section?

something like this :

```
$([some id]).animate({scrollTop: $elem.height()}, 800);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2j9Ur/)**

```
$(document).on("click","a",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr("href"),
            topSpace = 30;
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - topSpace
        }, 800);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $elem.scrollTop()}, 800);
```

http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

Answer (score 2):

In your stylesheet add this code it will work fine

```
html{scroll-behavior: smooth;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work on Safari and Internet Explorer, right?